# CakePHP Upgrade - now home page redirects to login form

Tags: php, cakephp

I just upgraded from CakePHP 2.1 to 2.4.

However, after the upgrade the home page redirects to */users/login* . I only made some small changes in bootstrap.php, as were introduced in CakePhp 2.2, but other than that I only upgraded the */lib/Cake/* folder.

Otherwise the site is working fine. I suppose I am only missing *$this->Auth->allow('*');* in a Controller, but which one?

Answer (score 0):

In order to exempt the home page from the Auth, I updated the AppController adding 
*$this->Auth->allow('display');* to the *beforeFilter()*.

Previously it was written as *$this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');*, but that no longer worked, so there seems to have been a change between CakePHP Version 2.1 and 2.4.